# Splitting a larger job into shorter Lambda functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a serverless lambda on AWS that loops through a (pandas) dataframe and for every individual index, invokes another Lambda (through SNS) that does the actual processing. The actual processing can take a few seconds to close to a minute.

I have tried putting a sleep timer in the loop.The dataframe has about 2000 rows and 3 columns. So, there are about 2000 Lambda calls to be made in 15 minutes.

If the sleep is too long, the top level lambda doesn't finish within 15 minutes. If the sleep is too low, then the individual lambdas timeout, probably because there are too many concurrent lambdas invoked. (Also, the lambdas read a json file which is quite big - about 30MB from an S3 object)

```
def invoke_controller(event, context):

    if event != '':
        message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
        function_name = message.get('function_name','DoSomething')

    sns_arn = sns_arn_prefix + function_name

    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        print('Publishing data for {} to SNS ({})'.format(row.Id, function_name))
        client = boto3.client('sns')
        response = client.publish(
            TopicArn=sns_arn,
            Message=json.dumps(dict(row)),
        )
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

I have considered splitting the dataframe and process them separately. But I am wondering if there is a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: post some code here so we can help you

Comment: @ALIBENALI Thank you. I have added the code snippet now.

Comment: Why would the lambdas timeout if there are too many concurrent instances? Do they use some shared resource on which they have to wait?

Comment: @NikolayManolov Thank you. Yes. The lambdas read a json file (which is quite big - about 30MB) from an S3 object. I could be wrong but I did not find a more efficient way of reading a file from within the lambda space.

Comment: ok, but do they also update the file? Does one lambda instance need to wait for another one to finish before it starts reading the same file? If they are just reading then they can read in parallel without affecting each other's execution time.

Comment: @NikolayManolov No. Not a requirement and not that something I am doing within the code. For a moment, I thought you were suggesting S3 has a limit on the concurrent reads. If this isn't a problem, why is running them in parallel especially when the number is as high as 500+ have I started seeing all of them timeout?

Comment: S3 has some throughput limit but it is very high and I would not expect it to be a problem but I guess it wouldn't hurt to time that.
The number of lambda instances in itself should not have an effect on how long it takes them to execute, unless there's something like a shared resource. I'm interested :)

Comment: @NikolayManolov I separated the code that reads from S3. It was taking about 5s and that is ruled out of time elapsed now. Things improved but the original issue of timeouts persist albeit with lesser frequency. I guess what I really need to do is decrease the concurrency of my lambda call invocation through SNS. I am considering using SQS instead of SNS or just use reserved concurrency limit on the lambda functions. Let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: I'm kinda confused as to why the lambda instance invoked via SNS would timeout. If you try to invoke more than the concurrency limit (1000 by default) the invocation would fail and be retried a couple of times before a final fail but that is different than a time out I think. I guess you could try and time different parts of the lambda to see if something eats up all of the time.

Comment: In any case, if the top level calling lambda does not need to wait for the results you could create a SQS queue where you push all the tasks. Then you have a couple of approaches either have SQS trigger a lambda to process the messages which would start as many lambdas as possible but you might still run into your current problem. Or have a lambda run on schedule every minute and process messages from the queue (this would in a very simplistic implementation limit you to 15 concurrent lambdas - 1 lambda per minute times 15min duration limit).